# Ios 11.2 beta universal links open my app and safari

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

On previous versions of the OS my universal links have been functioning correctly. In the iOS 11.2 beta when I click on a link that is defined in my Associated Domains, and whose path is defined in the apple-app-site-association file, my app opens. However, immediately after displaying my launch screen, safari also opens and my app is put in the background. Any explanation or possible solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Report it to Apple as a bug in the beta?

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure if it was a bug with my stuff or theirs. I have reported I'll wait and see what they say

Comment: @DavidRiediger Could you share the radar link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug with the beta. iOS 11.2 beta 3 solved the issue