# Universal Link broken in iOS 11.2

Tags: ios, ios11, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, deeplink

I am using **Branch deep links** in an app for sharing links to content in the app via social media. Everything was working fine quite a while.

When updating to **iOS 11.2** I encountered the following behavior:

1) After the update the Universal Links still worked.

2) I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it.

3) Since then, all links always open the Branch deep view in Safari.

4) Tapping "Open The App", opens the AppStore.

It does **not matter in which app** I tap on the link (Notes, WhatsApp, Messages, Facebook, ...), it is always the same behavior.

The Universal Link was **not bypassed** by tapping the "go to link" button in the upper right corner (when app was opened). I tested on three different devices (iPhone 5s, iPhone 6s, iPhone 7). All led to the same result.

I found out that there **was a bug in iOS 11 beta 2 which was fixed in the beta 3** ([Ios 11.2 beta universal links open my app and safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189912/ios-11-2-beta-universal-links-open-my-app-and-safari)), but it might have reappeared?!

Anyone having the same issues or a way to fix it?

Comment: I have this problem too: iOS 11.2.1 was released a couple of days ago and still seems to have this issue. There is a beta release in the developer centre (11.2.5) which may address this, but I cannot test this right now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Sometimes universal links don't work on iOS 11.2 for newly installed apps.

The symptoms are that clicking on a universal link won't open an app that is newly installed on a phone. The universal link takes the user to a web page and is prompted to download the app again.

Through testing here at Branch HQ we've discovered that the Apple App Site Associated Domains  file (`apple-app-site-association` file) isn't always downloaded after the app is installed, either when it's installed from the app store or from Xcode.

Removing the app, restarting the phone, re-installing the app, and waiting a minute or so seems to clear this up.  This is a horrible user experience obviously.

We have filed a [radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4999496467480576) with Apple and will continue to track this issue.

### Mitigations

**Set `$uri_redirect_mode`**

Setting the `$uri_redirect_mode` option on links can have Branch try to force the link to open the app, even if it might show an error to the user. You can read about this option [here, in the Branch docs.](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#forced-redirections)

Here's more info about turning on `$uri_redirect_mode` in your Branch Journey or Deepview banner, the web snippet that Branch shows the user if the ends up deep linking into a web browser:

[Advanced Journey Configuration](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/journeys/#auto-open-the-app-on-ios)

#### Deferred Deep Linking Mitigates This Problem

This issue is mitigated by Branch's deferred deep linking tech:  If the user opens the app from their home screen after the universal link is clicked, deferred deep linking still works, and the link content is shown in the app.

Comment: On all my test devices a first click on any link leads to the store. From then on I'm always redirected to the app. Annoying enough that it doesn't work on the first click but finally at least it works afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @clayjones94's Answer, I have been unable to get my iPad 2nd gen (iOS 12.1.1) to recover the ability to use Universal links after switching between release and debug targets.
Yesterday it suddenly started to work, but then after changing build-target, the universal link has again broken.

I've uninstalled, rebooted, installed, rebooted and so on.

I was, however able to test the functionality in a simulator, so for now, I would recommend attempting a fresh simulator to make sure your AASA file is correct on the server.

EDIT: if you have a proxy involved, that may also break the validation between the app and the website