# Dynamic link does not open the app, and "open in app" option not available in context menu

Tags: ios, firebase, ios-universal-links, firebase-dynamic-links

I just encountered a very weird behaviour with Firebase dynamic links.
It works perfectly on all of our test devices except for one.

This specific device is an iPhone-x, and the account was restored via iTunes (Not sure if this info is relevant, but i'm trying to give a full picture).

Our app is installed on this device from the app store (also tried deleting and reinstalling), but when trying to open a dynamic link it opens Safari instead, there we have the "open" button that opens the app store page of this app.

When trying to long tap on the link as suggested by developers that experienced the same issue, we have only one button that says "Open" which opens Safari again. I would expect that when the app is installed we would have two options:
1. "Open in Safari"
2. "Open in [App]"

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overall diagnoses here is that Universal Linking is not configured properly on the device. If Universal Links works on all other devices, then it is probably the case that the AASA file is not being downloaded properly. [iOS 11.2 has had issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801526/universal-link-broken-in-ios-11-2/47821378#47821378) with this recently.

### Check device logs

I suggest that you check the device logs when installing the application to see if the AASA file is being downloaded properly.

1) Delete your app and plug in the device to your computer

2) Open up Xcode and navigate to **Window > Devices & Simulators**

3) Select the device in the left-hand menu

4) In the bottom of the window you should see a triangle in a box. Clicking this will bring up the device logs.

[image]

5) Use a cmd-f to search for `applinks` and if your app downloaded the AASA correctly. You should see something like

`Added service 'applinks', appID 'RXXXXXXXP.io.branch.Branchsters', domain 'branchster.app.link'`

If this is not the case, then it looks like you AASA file is not being downloaded and you may need to delete the app, restart your phone, and try again.

Comment: better to filter for "swcd" (SharedWebCredential Daemon). Also at current time the "4)" step is not the same there is a button "Open Console" now.