# How to setup universal linking

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I am trying to setup universal linking on the website. I am following the guide at
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1

I set up my **apple-app-site-association** and can even access it at
https://devapp.meet2talk.com/apple-app-site-association

I also set app the capabilities in the app so that the associated domains include

`applinks:devapp.meet2talk.com`

Now when I check the domain link in apple validation tool I keep getting the following error:

`no apps with domain entitlements. 
The entitlement data used to verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. And how can I test if my universal links are working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your domain is now properly configured. Sometimes there is a delay for the validator to ensure that your domain is configured. You can verify that it is set up correctly at [https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/?domain=https:%2F%2Fdevapp.meet2talk.com#resultsbox). Now when you run your application you can ensure that your AASA file is being downloaded correctly. Do this by checking the device logs. You can see how to do this in [my other post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681530/dynamic-link-does-not-open-the-app-and-open-in-app-option-not-available-in-co/48714848#48714848)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error when checking my domain with a validator.

My project was compiling without errors but my app would not launch when I clicked on a link that was configured for universal linking.

I resolved by selecting the correct Provisioning Profile in XCode (General-> Signing-> Provisioning Profile).  I generated the provisioning profile on the Apple Developer site for my developer account.  The profile was for my application and included the Associated Domains Capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending "applinks:" before your associated domain name under Associated Domains in Project Entitlement file (obviously, after enabling Associated Domains from Capabilities).