# Does testflight change App ID?

Tags: ios, cordova, testflight, ios-universal-links

I have an app, which uses Apple Universal Links feature. So, this app should be opened, when user clicks on my web site link. But, somehow, this happens. One of the reasons is wrong App ID. Can test flight change it somehow?

UPD: The Apple App ID is a two part string used to identify one or more apps. Specifically, the Apple app ID is your team ID and bundle ID joined with a period, for example: 1A234H7ABC.com.yourdomain.YourApp.

Comment: what "appId" are you referring to?

Comment: appId is teamId +BoundleId

Answer (score 3):

No, the app ID should not change. The bundle ID should never change and neither should the team ID. You should [check your device logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681530/dynamic-link-does-not-open-the-app-and-open-in-app-option-not-available-in-co/48714848#48714848) when installing the app to see if the AASA file is getting downloaded. This could be an [iOS 11.2 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801526/universal-link-broken-in-ios-11-2/47821378#47821378) in which you'll have to delete the app and re-download it.