# Broken universal link

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

The universal link which is working successfully sometimes doesn't work.

After the updated app or restart the device, the Universal Link is working. Has any expiring time for a universal link?

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 11.2, the AASA file will fail to install on the device making Universal Links fail. When you install or update the app, this should fix the issue. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801526/universal-link-broken-in-ios-11-2/47821378#47821378).