# Intermittent universal links issue on iOS 11.2.6

Tags: swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am running into an issue with universal links and not sure what's going on. I am not using Branch or any third party.
Once i restart the phone, it works. After that for some reason, it stopped working, and I have to restart the phone again.

Not only my phone but also happening on the other phones.
Have any one run into that issue?

Best,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801526/universal-link-broken-in-ios-11-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Universal Link broken in iOS 11.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801526/universal-link-broken-in-ios-11-2)

Comment: I am not using Branch or any third party btw.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with iOS 11.2. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801526/universal-link-broken-in-ios-11-2) mentioned in the comments. This is not an issue with the third-party, it is an issue with iOS 11.2 not downloading the AASA file consistently. Branch and other third party services still leverage this AASA file downloading to run their deep linking. I have yet to run into this issue in iOS 11.3, but the [radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4999496467480576) is still open.

Comment: Thanks, found the note on Branch's blog website about this issue